# Kubernetes LoadBalancer service on AKS via helm is not accessible

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm working on a project in which I need to deploy a simple NodeJs application using Kubernetes, Helm and Azure Kubernetes Service.

Here's What I have tried:

**My `Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 32000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Here's my `mychart/values.yaml`:**

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
  # registry: docker.io
  repository: registry-1.docker.io/arycloud/docker-web-app
  tag: 0.3
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

service:
  name: http
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 32000
  internalPort: 32000

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  paths: []
  hosts:
    - name: mychart.local
      path: /
  tls: []

resources: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

**And my node `server.js`:**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 32000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world from container.\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

> **Update:** Template files:

**From `templates/deployment.yaml`:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "mychart.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 32000
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 32000
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 32000
            initialDelaySeconds: 3
            periodSeconds: 3
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

**From `templates/service.yaml`:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "mychart.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

> **Update: a screenshot of external IP:**
>   [image]
>   Here's the output of `kubectl get svc node-release-mychart -oyaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-01-26T11:28:27Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: node-release
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Tiller
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mychart
    helm.sh/chart: mychart-0.1.0
  name: node-release-mychart
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "127367"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/node-release-mychart
  uid: 8031f3b6-215d-11e9-bb89-462a1bcec690
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.0.223.27
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 32402
    port: 32000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 32000
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: node-release
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mychart
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.240.0.7
```

I have created a cluster on AKS then run the `get-credentials` command from my mac os terminal and it works fine, then I have tagged and pushed my docker image to `dockerhub` and the docker container is also working fine, after that I have created a helm chart and update the `values.yaml` accordingly and run the `helm install` command, it install my application to `aks` and the service provide an `external IP`, in the kubernetes dashboard the `pods` are in `running` state but when I try to access my application via `Etxernal_IP:80` it doesn't load my application.

Comment: why dont you post template files?

Comment: Added template files also, take a look, please!

Comment: also, does you application work internally? without service? can you hit the pod endpoint and confirm it works? i suspect not. you are publishing port 80 on the pod, not 32000

Comment: how can I test that?

Comment: `kubectl port-forward podname portnumber` and then use your browser to access localhost:port

Comment: yes, it is working from the pod internally.

Comment: it wont work through the service, because you published wrong port (80, not 32000)

Comment: do I need to change the port under `service -> port : 32000`?

Comment: I have changed the `port` to `32000` inside my `service` and update the above also, but it still not loading the service.

Comment: inside the pod definition, your service was correct, pod is wrong

Comment: do I need to change the `containerPort` under `ports:` in `deployment.yaml`?

Comment: yes, thats the port that gets exposed inside k8s

Comment: I have also updated the port in `deployment.yaml` to `32000` but it still not loading the `service`.

Comment: did you try externalip:32000? i'm lost in what changes you have made

Comment: Yes, I'm trying the `EXTERNAL_IP:32000`, I'm updating the code in the question above also when making any change here at my system, so the code i question is updated.

Comment: ok, can you try doing `kubectl port-forward svc/service_name_goes_here 32000:32000` and try with your browser?

Comment: When hit this URL, it returns this error in the console: `E0126 16:25:57.135728   18839 portforward.go:391] an error occurred forwarding 32000 -> 300: error forwarding port 300 to pod 5ab3473538e8ca9150dd701b9c92725d7314583ad9e74b4a2d51c4f48dcb69a4, uid : exit status 1: 2019/01/26 11:25:57 socat[6211] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:300, 16): Connection refused`

Comment: There was type in the `service.yaml` as `300` now I changed it to `32000` and by port-forwarding it's working.

Comment: But with the `Externa_IP:32000` it's still not working.

Comment: if its working with port-forwarding it should work with external ip. check the ip you are using. you can get proper ip with: `kubectl get svc`

Comment: I'm already trying in this way...but it's not working!

Comment: ok, can you add output from `kubectl get deploy svc` into the answer?

Comment: I have added a screenshot, take a look, please!

Comment: that isnt an external ip for sure, can you show output of: `kubectl get svc node-release-mychart -oyaml`?

Comment: Added in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact you've added the annotation to use internal load balancer (so not exposed publicly, only available inside vnet). To fix that remove this part from the service definition:

```
annotations:
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

Comment: i'm trying to figure out when this parameter moves out of "beta" !  Many have it as a go-to setup now.

Comment: what do you mean "beta"? @granadaCoder

Comment: service.beta.kubernetes.io . <second word

Comment: oh, ok :) no idea, sorry. you could try asking in #sig-azure in k8s slack